# How to create a self signed certificate containing a CRL Distribution point

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl

I have created a Self Signed Certificate using makecert.exe by reading the following msdn link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx

But, the Certificate created using the command examples mentioned doesn't have any CRL Distribution Point in the Certificate created, which is why when running my WCF service, I get an exception that - `The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate`.

How can I create a Self Signed Certificate that also has a CRL Distribution Point inside it, so that I don't have to use, `revocationMode='NoCheck'`?

Is it even possible using `makecert.exe`? and if not, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with doing it manually for the certificate generation, I use a program that helps with that, [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/). It's an open source utility for managing certificates, keys, signing and CAs, with far more options than makecert.

It lets you create a self-signed certificate with full control over each data it contains, one of such fields being the CRL distribution points:
[image: CRL option with XCA]

I have no idea if makecert is actually capable of that, or how to do it, but for me using XCA is fine, and certainly possible to meet your requirement.